# Accessing for_each variables of type list(object) from a module

Tags: terraform

I've created a module which does port-forwarding for VM's and theres a variable inside of type list(object) which I am having trouble referring to.

There's a main.tf file inside proxmox-instance (tree included below) with our variable inside of it. It has a for_each loop and **I am trying to use the objects inside the variable loop of ./proxmox-instance/main.tf on a different directry - the . directory inside ./main.tf.**

```
.
├── main.tf
├── output.tf
└── proxmox-instance
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf
    ├── providers.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

I do not fully understand how the syntax works when referring variables from a different folder.

Here's the code snippet

```
variable "forwarded_ports" {
  description = "Your Template name - Will be cloned from this template"
  type = list(object({
    host_port  = number
    guest_port = number
  }))
  default = [{
    "host_port"  = 2222,
    "guest_port" = 22
  }]
}
```

The ./proxmox-instance/main.tf looks like this

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = [for k in forwarded_ports : k]

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port                                                  # Custom Port for ingress connections
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```

#### The error happens in the code section below while trying to refer to

`forwarded_ports.host_port`
`forwarded_ports.guest_port`

```
module "instance" {
  source = "./proxmox-instance"

  vm_name       = "Terraform"
  template_name = "ubuntu-20.04"

  # cloud-init settings
  ipconfig0           = "ip=dhcp"
  cloud_init_user     = "ubuntu"
  cloud_init_password = "password"

  forwarded_ports.host_port = 2222
  forwarded_ports.guest_port = 22
}
```

I've tried playing with the syntax for host / guest port but couldn't fully understand it and so and kept receving errors..

**Output 1/2**

```
  forwarded_ports.host_port  = 2222
  forwarded_ports.guest_port = 22

Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on main.tf line 17, in module "instance":
│   17:   forwarded_ports.guest_port = 22
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

**Output 2/2**

```
 forwarded_ports = [{
    host_port  = 2222
    guest_port = 22
  }]

│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 5, in module "instance":
│    5: module "instance" {
│
│ The argument "host_port" is required, but no definition was found.

│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 5, in module "instance":
│    5: module "instance" {
│
│ The argument "guest_port" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: Can you also say where exactly in the code is the error happening? It's almost impossible to say looking at only the error output.

Comment: @MarkoE Apologies, i've edited the original post

Comment: Ok, does the error output show the line in that file which is offending?

Comment: @MarkoE edited my question again - I tried making a way to replicate but couldn't upload files as providers.tf containers sensitive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an object in a variable, you have to define it in much the same way that your default is used within the module.

The first error you get explains it best:

```
Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on main.tf line 17, in module "instance":
│   17:   forwarded_ports.guest_port = 22
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

To reference the `forwarded_ports` variable in your module, you should pass it as an argument to the module.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
module "instance" {
  source = "./proxmox-instance"

  vm_name       = "Terraform"
  template_name = "ubuntu-20.04"

  # cloud-init settings
  ipconfig0           = "ip=dhcp"
  cloud_init_user     = "ubuntu"
  cloud_init_password = "password"

  forwarded_ports = [{
    host_port  = 2222
    guest_port = 22
  }]
}
```

`variables` inside of modules are inputs in the module block. Any variable that does *NOT* contain a default is required, and those that contain a default are optional.

The second error from **Output 2/2**:

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 5, in module "instance":
│    5: module "instance" {
│
│ The argument "host_port" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Indicates that there are additional variables named `host_port` and `guest_port` that are unrelated to the `forwarded_ports` variable and are apparently required. Your code isn't showing this, but I suspect you'll find both of these in your module `variables.tf` file. The likely reason you're seeing this error is because you're correctly defining `forwarded_ports` in that example, but missing other unrelated arguments with names that are confusing you.

To understand more about module inputs, see [Terraform's documentation on Input Variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables).

`./proxmox-instance/main.tf`

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = [for k in forwarded_ports : k]
...
```

This should be `var.forwarded_ports` and should look something like this:

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  for_each = [for k in var.forwarded_ports : k]

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port     
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```

Comment: You are actually correct. I didn't even notice but It had some extra variables on it.

Comment: Although I am having a different issue now this did help me resolve my orignial issue so i'll mark it as the anwser

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, at least two things are wrong [could be more because of missing code I can not commit]

1: In your `./proxmox-instance/main.tf` the `for_each = [for k in forwarded_ports : k]` needs to refer to a variable defined in terraform.

**Correct Reference :**

```
resource "iptables_nat" "dnat-front" {
  # Creates an entry for each template specified
  for_each = [for k in var.forwarded_ports : k] ## change is ** var.forwarded_ports **

  name           = "iptable-${var.vm_name}-${each.value.host_port}-to-${each.value.guest_port}"
  on_cidr_blocks = ["195.201.172.34"] # Proxmox network device IP here

  dnat {
    iface    = "enp7s0"
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port  = each.value.host_port                                                  # Custom Port for ingress connections
    nat_ip   = "${proxmox_vm_qemu.vm.default_ipv4_address}:${each.value.guest_port}" # VM Internal IP here
  }
}
```

`[for k in var.forwarded_ports : k]` will give you following tuple on which you have work in your module interface call.

```
[
  {
    "guest_port" = 22
    "host_port" = 2222
  },
]
```

> you can verify this in terraform console. More Details on Terraform Console at [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/console)

2: Your module interface call is also wrong, the error message `An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.` is complaining about the
`forwarded_ports.host_port = 2222` and `forwarded_ports.guest_port = 22`.

As the code snippet pasted is not complete here, seems like a few other variables and resources are missing. Please try to use something like

```
module "instance" {
  source = "./proxmox-instance"

  vm_name       = "Terraform"
  template_name = "ubuntu-20.04"

  # cloud-init settings
  ipconfig0           = "ip=dhcp"
  cloud_init_user     = "ubuntu"
  cloud_init_password = "password"

  ## module will refer to the variables and then pass them in the correct type.
  forwarded_ports = [
    {
      host_port = 2222
      guest_port = 22
    },
    {
      host_port = another_value
      guest_port = another_value
    },
  ]
}
```

I hope this helps.